# Identify a 1940s resistor type

Tags: resistors, identification

[image: Resistors]

Inside a c.1942 Marconi 340 Output Power Meter are three rotary switches of a type and aesthetic beauty I've not come across before, but the resistors pictured are the main subject of this question - does anyone know what this type of resistor is called?

The resistance values handwritten  on them are far from any current preferred value which suggests to me that they were handmade to special values to suit the instrument.

Including a more overall image of the switch assembly for the interest of others.

[image: switch]

Edit: Added part schematic. The resistors are referred to as "padding" resistors and were made up to complement the impedance of associated transformer windings for impedance matching to the signal source.

[image: schematic]

Edit: Closer inspection reveals stamped markings on the rear faces of the resistors: a circle with - I think - the letters "MELL" and the number "309" beneath. Google not giving much of any help.

[image: rear]

Comment: Resistor seems to be correct. Made from copper to specific values... are you going to replace them? Good luck as I don’t think you will get them "off the shelf".

Comment: What's under the paper? No way is a metal plate of that width 4200 Ohms. And what does the "TYPE" thing say? We can't quite read it.

Comment: TYPE (printed, or stamped, in upper case) TB4731 (handwritten). Some others - impossible to photograph - are labelled by hand "SET 76". The transformer is also labelled "76" in a similar hand.

Comment: No plan to replace them, the whole instrument set me back a whopping AUD$20 and appears to work - although I can't vouch for its accuracy. More a question out of interest.

Comment: Sounds like a hand made matched set! This would have been a precision instrument in its day.

Comment: I just measured all of the resistors whose labels I was able to read. All measured within one ohm of the labelled values after 80 years! Now I really want to know how they are made or what they're specifically called, but now much less inclined to cut one open.

Comment: MELL is almost certainly Marconi Electronics (or possibly Marconi-Ekco) Laboratories Limited which may help further search, but I think these were made (and rubber stamped!) in house.

Comment: The pieces are coming together...

Answer (score 3):

The construction of this rotary switch reminds me of the switches in a decade resistance box. The resistors are most likely **wire-wound resistors**. They may have been specially wound or even trimmed to the exact value required. Given that this instrument operates on AC signals in the audio frequency range, it's likely that these are **non-inductively wound** resistors. This means that the wire is coiled in such a way as to minimise the inductance of the component. A normal wire-wound resistor would be wound in a similar way to an inductor, i.e. a simple coil. The insulating material at the core of the component may be **mica**, which is a mineral that may be cleaved into thin sheets. It's a good insulator and can withstand high temperatures, and was commonly use to make capacitors.

All in all, a really nice example of a special-purpose component in a piece of precision test equipment.

Answer (score 2):

"Stud faders" though the ones I've seen have lumps of silver as the contacts.
[image]

This one is actually a very rare (failed experimental) stereo stud fader, probably from the 1960s; each channel has two contacts to allow for a constant impedance attenuator, with 180 degree total rotation.

The experiment failed, because the studs for the two channels weren't perfectly aligned, so the "stud noise" (steps in attenuation) happened at different times on each channel, and the stereo image jumped slightly left and right during a fade, which was found to be a bit unsettling during listening tests.

[image]

Shows the 180 degree scale and proper Bembridge knob.

I'm not certain but I expect you'll find wirewound resistors, possibly even hand wound round either ceramic or (if these are low-ish power 1W or less) Tufnol plates. If one is broken, or so far off value you need to replace it anyway, you can take it apart to verify.

Comment: For a failure, it's a beautiful failure.

Comment: The DeLorean of switches?

Comment: Single channel stud faders were in use in BBC Radio from probably the era of your attenuator until 1981 when the last Type B Desk (mixer) was retired. Page 2 here shows them in vivo, and dissected. http://www.orbem.co.uk/typea/typea2.htm

Comment: Just...wow. Thank you for the lead.